# Отображение дней недели на русском

Tags: php, wordpress

Добрый вечер всем пользователям данного форума, прошу помощи с отображение даты на сайте.
На данный момент вывожу следующим образом

```
<div class="today">Сегодня: <?php echo date('d.m.y l'); ?></div>
```

В результате чего получаю дату и день недели на английском языке. Помогите отредактировать код что бы дата была на русском

Comment: В WordPress можно использовать функцию wp_date, она выводит дату на языке сайта.

Answer (score 0):

Как по мне, самый короткий способ выглядит так:

```
$day=array('','Понедельник','Вторник','Среда','Четверг','Пятница','Суббота','Воскресенье',);
echo '<div class="today">Сегодня: '.date('d.m.y').' '.$day[date("N")].'</div>';
```